# Views in Linear Layout not getting equal space with android:layout_weight attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

As describe in the topic's title, I have 3 `TextView` and I would like them to share the whole screen's width using the `android:layout_weight` attribute, but doing so didn't get the sought results.

LinearLayout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tour1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Tour \n disponibili  \n 21" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tour2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Tour \n prenotabili  \n 16" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tour3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Tour \n preferiti  \n 3" />
```

result in Portrait:

[image: Portrait]

result in Landscape:

[image: Landscape]

where is the elephant?

ps. As you can notice from the screenshot, a second problem arises: Why the first 2 `TextView` get stretched in height? How can I fix this unpredictable behavior?

Comment: you didn't assign the weightSum to linearLayout

Comment: `weightSum` is not necesseary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

in your `LinearLayout`.

`wrap_content` means that the 'ViewGroup`will have the size which is big enough to enclose its content, while`match_parent` will make it as big as its parent.

Answer (score 1):

The `LinearLayout` width is set to `wrap_content`. Set it to `match_parent` and the views will stretch to the whole screen width.